# An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf

When Invoking my service i found the same error,

I have A separate solution for creating my entities where i have created entities

And Have One another separate solution where i define my data access layer and a service layer

The service has published well but when i am trying to invoke the methods in service it gives the following error.

Please Assists me how to resolve this problem

Comment: Enable WCF tracing.  Check the event viewer.  Check any logging you may have added to the service or code.  Somewhere an unhandled exception is being thrown - you need to find out where and handle it.

Comment: @Tim thanks,
previously i was using ef6.0 but when i change it to ef5.0 all things working fine for me.
i don't know the reason behind it?have u and idea about this?

Comment: There is not enough information in your question to give you a good answer.  That's why I said (in my previous comment) to enable WCF tracing, check the event viewer and any additional logging your service may be doing (i.e., that you implemented).